# Passing data from C to Haskell and back

Tags: haskell, ffi

I am currently writing Haskell bindings to the GEGL library, which is originally written in C. It's my first time using the FFI, so I may have missed something.

My Problem is, that I get segfaults at code like this:

```
-- | Simple iteration over a rectangle section of a buffer.
iterateOver   
  :: GeglBuffer               -- ^ Target buffer
  -> GeglRectangle            -- ^ Rectangle to iterate over
  -> BablFormat               -- ^ Pixel format
  -> GeglAccessMode           -- ^ Access mode to pixel data
  -> GeglAbyssPolicy          -- ^ Abbyss policy for pixel data
  -> (Pixel -> Pixel) -- Function to apply to each pixel
  -> IO ()
iterateOver buf rect form am ap func = do
  traceIO "start"
  (FFI.GeglBufferIterator iterPtr) <- gegl_buffer_iterator_new buf rect form am ap
  traceIO "new iterator"
  untilM_ (do
    floats <-  map (\(CFloat f) -> f) <$> FFI.c_gegl_peek_data iterPtr -- Code breaks here
    traceIO "peeked data"
    let ops =  buildPixelList rect floats
        nps =  map func ops
        nfl =  map CFloat $ buildFloatList nps
    FFI.c_gegl_poke_data iterPtr nfl
    traceIO "poked data"                                                        
    ) ( not <$> gegl_buffer_iterator_next (FFI.GeglBufferIterator iterPtr))
  traceIO "finished"
```

The `c_gegl_peek_data` function has been written with `inline-c` and looks as follows:

```
-- | Get the list of pixel data out of a 'GeglBufferIterator'.
c_gegl_peek_data
  :: GeglBufferIteratorDummy -- ^ Iterator to take data from
  -> IO [CFloat]
c_gegl_peek_data ptr = do
  fptr <- [C.block| float * {
    GeglBufferIterator * cptr =  $(void * ptr);
    float * a = (float *) cptr->data[0];
    return a;
    }|]
  (CInt length) <- [C.block| int {
    GeglBufferIterator * cptr = $(void * ptr);
    int a = cptr->length;
    return a;
    }|]
  peekArray (fromIntegral length :: Int) fptr
```

Can anyone of you point out, where my error is?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here is a small minimal self-contained example of the same problem. it only requires the `inline-c` package.

```
{-#LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-#LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-#LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-#LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Main where

import qualified Language.C.Inline as C
import Foreign.Marshal.Array
import Debug.Trace

main :: IO ()
main = do
  traceIO "start"
  ptr <- [C.block| int * {
    int a[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    return a;
    }|]
  traceIO "got pointer"
  a <- peekArray 5 ptr
  traceIO "peeked pointer"
  putStrLn $ show a
  traceIO "finish"
```

Furthermore I add the cabal file for this example:

```
name:                sandbox
version:             0.0.0.0
synopsis:            Small example
author:              nek0
maintainer:          nek0@nek0.eu
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable sandbox
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  c-sources:           app/Main.c
  ghc-options:         -Wall -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                     , inline-c
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Comment: Can you recreate the behaviour in a [mcve]? Otherwise it will be difficult to reproduce the behaviour completely. Either way, I _guess_ that at some point memory that's owned by GEGL gets freed by something in your Haskell code. And the second `free()` tends to segfault at the weirdest times (after all, it's undefined behaviour).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. added a small example. I am not aware of freeing any pointers in my code.

Comment: As a non-static `int[5]`, you may not use the returned pointer after you've left its scope. That's basically the same -> UB.

Comment: Thank you so much. with a `static` prepending tha variable the example works. I'll try to get my project working with it, but I see a problem with non constant initializers when compiling. I'll try to solve that. Would you like to write a proper answer so I can accept it?

Comment: after some hours tinkering with it it now finally works. Thank you very much.